# Regular expression for replacing function call with direct access

Tags: regex, regex-group

I'd like to replace a function call in the first format:

```
get(store, 'data.field1.field2', defaultVal) // there can be more fields on the second part
```

with this:

```
data?.field1?.field2 || defaultVal
```

using regex search replace within the project or possibly using sed or other tools.

I've tried a few expressions but couldn't figure out how to name and split the sections for replace. Any thoughts?

Comment: What language?.

Comment: Could you add the regex you tried so far ?

Comment: What are the rules? Please provide your attempts to see what is wrong

Comment: I'll use external tools to do it. So I guess language doesn't matter?

I've used `get\(.+,(.+),.+\)` and tried named groups but couldn't go much far.

Comment: Aha, so the last two arguments inside `(...)` on a line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd use `perl`:

```
perl -pe 's{get\(.*,\s*'"'"'(.+)'"'"',\s*(.+)\)}{join("?.", split(/\./,$1)) . " || " . $2}ge' file
```

The `get\(.*,\s*'(.+)',\s*(.+)\)` regex (see [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/K8VHoz/2)) matches `get(`, captures the last two arguments, splits the first one with a dot joining them back with `?.` and appends `||` with the second capture.

Comment: One more question though, how can we make the default value part optional? e.g. the text could be in this format as well: `get(store, 'data.field1')`. Output should be: `data?.field1` in this case.